# For a luekemia patient - how does the chemotherapy fixes the bone marrow to not produce immature cells

Tags: cancer

For ALL patient [this link](https://www.stjude.org/disease/acute-lymphoblastic-leukemia-all.html) says 90% of the children are cured.   It has high survival rate. From what I understand is that - luekemia is type of cancer where the immature cells does not turn into mature cells. How does the chemotherapy with other drugs - fixes the bone marrow immature cells defect?

```
What are the survival rates for acute lymphoblastic leukemia?
About 98 percent of children with ALL go into remission within weeks after starting treatment.
About 90 percent of those children can be cured. Patients are considered cured after 10 years in remission.
```

Answer (score 2):

Chemotherapy in general works by killing (hopefully all) cancerous cells, while leaving the patient / healthy cells alive.
The drugs used for this usually are in principle toxins/poisons, but are more deadly to cancer cells, since these cells are growing very quickly compared to healthy cells. This general strategy is true for a lot of [different types of drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemotherapy#Types) (and cancers). However, because the drugs are still generally toxic they are [hard to dose correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemotherapy#Dosage) and also the reason why chemotherapy often has quite strong side-effects.
Additionally cancer can quickly evolve to gain resistance to specific drugs, which is why nowadays often a combination of multiple drugs at once is used.

In leukemia - which is a form of cancer where the blood and immune cell precursor cells in the bone marrow become cancerous - additional ways of selectively killing the cancer are radiation therapy (of the affected bones) and in some cases complete bone marrow transplants (which have their own issues, so they are not usually  used as first option).